# Showing image (photo) stored as PostGIS base64 in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcmap, image, html-popup

I have a PostGIS table which stores point data with images as attribute (in base64 data type).

I would like to show the pictures from the column "bild" of the attribute table which look like this in ArcMap:

[image]

What I want to do is to click a point object in the map view and then the attribute data of the point will be shown together with the corresponding picture. I have found [How to read FieldTypeBlob from graphic.attributes](http://community.esri.com/thread/76017) and followed their tips as follows in ArcMap but it still does not work:

[image]

I have verified the text for the images by pasting it to a web browser and it shows the pictures without problem.

How can I solve this in ArcMap 10.3?